# WebClient Passing Parameters With Space Issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webclient

I want to download string by calling api in which i have to pass some parameters 
which contains space like :

```
String myUrl = AppConstants.BASE_URL + AppConstants.getFileteredList + Name + "," + LastName;

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri(myUrl,UriKind.Absolute);
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += wc_DownloadStringCompleted;
```

it looks like this

```
http://demo.com/Api/getFileteredList?data=abc%20xyz,abc%20xyz
```

but in wc_DownloadStringCompleted , e.result throws and exception like

> The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

i have tried "Uri.EscapeUriString" and also tried to implement using "HttpWebRequest" but getting same error.

Please help me out this.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its just a Malformed URL. If you peek myUrl you would notice a missing ? or something probably.

Can you check and port more details in your question.

Comment: i have posted sample URL and it is proper when  i am posting this in browser it is wroking.

Comment: I see. You must have the comma url encoded too!

, = %2C

Browser does that for you but WebClient does not apparently.

Comment: for that i tried like this : Uri.EscapeUriString(String myUrl = AppConstants.BASE_URL + AppConstants.getFileteredList + Name + "," + LastName);

Comment: Which is returning me the exact Uri which i want

Comment: In that case try

String myUrl = AppConstants.BASE_URL + AppConstants.getFileteredList + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Name + "," + LastName);